# Android App Location using "import android.location.*;"

Tags: android, location

I'd make an app that tells me in which latitude and longitude I am.

I followed exactly this one (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#BestPerformance) but the last row

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

is red underlined.

I use "import android.location.*;" and when I do the debug I step into that call.
The problem is that in LocationManager.java there are these wrong "imports":

```
import com.android.internal.location.ProviderProperties;
import android.annotation.RequiresPermission;
import android.annotation.SystemApi;
import android.annotation.TestApi;
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding those

import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;

Answer (score 0):

Try using this imports:

```
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
```

Comment: You need to use those import, you can't use a general import like that.

Comment: Actually I do import only those two (adding also LocationListener) but the problem remains: 
in LocationManager.java I still have those 4 error imports :(